# Audio recorder on Ubuntu MATE 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, audio-recording

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04, i have just installed audio recorder [from PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eaudio-recorder/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and I have tried also to install it from deb package.
In both cases, when i launch it i get this error:

> (audio-recorder:11599): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 23:00:47.063: Settings schema 'org.gnome.audio-recorder' is not installed
>
> Rilevato trace/breakpoint (core dump creato)

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: It is unclear. Which PPA? Which audio recorder?

Comment: Sorry, i just copied the question i've made on launchpad and you are right it's not clear. 
This is the launchpad page:

https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audio-recorder/ppa
sudo apt-get install --reinstall audio-recorder
```

and use it. I can't reproduce the problem on clean Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS VM.

---

Please note that missed schema is shipped with package:

> ```
> $ dpkg -L audio-recorder | grep org
> /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.audio-recorder.gschema.xml
>
> $ dpkg -S org.gnome.audio-recorder
> audio-recorder: /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.audio-recorder.gschema.xml
>
> $ apt-cache policy audio-recorder 
> audio-recorder:
>   Installed: 2.1.3~bionic
>   Candidate: 2.1.3~bionic
>   Version table:
>  *** 2.1.3~bionic 500
>         500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
>         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
> ```

Comment: I installed it exactly in that way. At the moment i can't try dpkg you suggest, i'll try as soon as i get home

Comment: I'm in late, sorry. I tried to answer but i couldn't format my text in a readble way; anyway i solved the problem by downloading source code and compiling it.